Design Patterns for Implementing Offline Support and Data Synchronization in a Blazor WebAssembly Application
I am developing a Blazor WebAssembly project that will be deployed as a web application with offline capabilities. The application should: Load data into browser storage (IndexedDB) when the client's device is connected to the network. Use the data from IndexedDB to function offline when the system loses network connectivity. Sync any changes made to the offline data (stored in IndexedDB) with the server database when the device is back online.
Sync Approaches Considered I am considering the following approaches for data synchronization:
Manual Sync: Provide a "Sync" button in the UI that the user can click to trigger data synchronization when the network is available. Timely Sync: Use a worker service to periodically check for network connectivity and attempt synchronization at defined intervals.
Event-Based Sync: Automatically trigger synchronization the moment the device regains network connectivity.
Question
I am looking for design patterns or best practices that can help me implement: Reliable offline functionality using IndexedDB in a Blazor WebAssembly application. Efficient data synchronization with the server, especially in scenarios involving conflicts or concurrent updates. Are there any design patterns, libraries, or tools in the Blazor ecosystem or beyond that are particularly suited for building offline-capable applications with these synchronization requirements?
Any guidance, examples, or references would be highly appreciated!

This question is opinion based which is off-topic. Please take a tour and visit Help center to have better understanding about StackOverflow
